# How is this adjectival phrase correctly declined?

Tags: declension, compound

This is a sentence from I. Asimov's, I, Robot:

> The miles of relays and photocells had given way to the spongy globe of plantinumiridium about the size of a human brain.

I have translated it with an adjectival phrase:

> Die Meilen von Relais und Fotozellen waren der schwammartigen, ungefähr **menschliche gehirngroßen** Kugel aus Platin-Iridium gewichen.

But I have 2 questions. 1) "gehirngroß" is a compounded adjective, but I cannot find a reference describing such compounding. For instance, Google tells me that "house-sized", translates to "hausgroß", but "dog-sized" translates to "hundegroß", not "hundgroß". Assuming Google is correct, how can I learn the rules for doing this type of compounding?

2. I am not sure how the word "menschlich" should be declined above, since it is an adjective describing Gehirn, but stands before the word "gehirngroß".

Comment: The first thing to note for an engineer is that in German it's kilometers ;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

»Kugel« is female in German, so it would be

> waren der [...] Kugel [...] gewichen.

The way you write »menschliche gehirngroßen« (disregarding declination for the moment) it implies that the sphere is human. Which I hope it is not.

I don't know any rules about when exactly an *e* or an *s* occur between the two parts of a composite word, but »gehirngroßen« is correct.

So if you want to stick with your construction, I'd say

> waren einer schwammartigen, ungefähr menschenhirngroßen Kugel [...] gewichen.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Raketenolli's translation is "von ungefähr/etwa der Größe eines menschlichen Gehirns".

So the full sentence would translate to:

> Die Meilen von Relais und Fotozellen waren der schwammartigen Kugel aus Platin-Iridium von etwa der Größe eines menschlichen Gehirns gewichen.

A subclause is also an option:

> Die Meilen von Relais und Fotozellen waren der schwammartigen Kugel aus Platin-Iridium gewichen, die etwa die Größe eines menschlichen Gehirns hatte.

Comment: Delighted to see these alternatives. But I would have thought the relative clause had to be put with the noun to which it refers: "Die Meilen von Relais und Fotozellen waren der schwammartigen Kugel, die etwa die Größe eines menschlichen Gehirns hatte, aus Platin-Iridium gewichen."

Comment: <nitpick>While technically not answering the question as asked</nitpick>, this is absolutely the more elegant way to put it in German. Interestingly, it is also closer to the English original.